# Having issues with sql while using group by, rank and where

Tags: php, sql, database

Having issues with sql while using group by, rank and where
Am trying to group and rank from a table in my database and have been able to solve that so now i want to use where column is equal to value.
Here is my code

```
SELECT g1.adnumber , g1.subject_id , g1.score ,
COUNT(*) AS rank FROM tbl_result AS g1 
JOIN tbl_result AS g2 
ON (g2.score, g2.adnumber) >= (g1.score, g1.adnumber) 
AND g1.subject_id = g2.subject_id 
GROUP BY g1.adnumber , g1.subject_id , g1.score 
ORDER BY g1.subject_id , rank 
where g1.adnumber = 'demonumber'
```

This is the error am getting

> **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'where g1.adnumber = 'ctydemo' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not just put a `where` clause at the end. You need to have the right [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Roughly explained you must have this order of a select:

```
SELECT
    *
[FROM]
[WHERE where_condition]
[GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
  [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
[HAVING where_condition]
[ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
  [ASC | DESC], ...]
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

in your case the query might work like so. Look at the changes `JOIN, ON, WHERE, AND`

```
SELECT
    g1.adnumber,
    g1.subject_id,
    g1.score,
    COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM tbl_result AS g1 
    JOIN tbl_result AS g2 
    ON g1.subject_id = g2.subject_id 
WHERE g1.adnumber = 'demonumber'
   # not sure what you are trying with the next line
   # AND (g2.score, g2.adnumber) >= (g1.score, g1.adnumber) 
   # maybe something like this:
   AND g2.score >= g1.score
   AND g2.adnumber >= g1.adnumber
GROUP BY 
    g1.adnumber,
    g1.subject_id,
    g1.score 
ORDER BY 
    g1.subject_id,
    g1.rank
```

Answer (score 2):

Where statements should be before group by & order by statements.

*This should work (NOT TESTED)*

```
SELECT 
    g1.adnumber , g1.subject_id , g1.score , COUNT(*) AS rank 
FROM 
    tbl_result AS g1 JOIN tbl_result AS g2 ON (g2.score, g2.adnumber) >= (g1.score, g1.adnumber) AND g1.subject_id = g2.subject_id 
WHERE 
    g1.adnumber = 'demonumber'
GROUP BY 
    g1.adnumber , g1.subject_id , g1.score 
ORDER BY 
    g1.subject_id , rank
```

Comment: Because Where clause is in right place, I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the wrong execution syntax.**In your SQL where clause should be placed before group by**. Please try the below SQL

```
SELECT g1.adnumber , g1.subject_id , g1.score ,
COUNT(*) AS rank FROM tbl_result AS g1 
JOIN tbl_result AS g2 
ON (g2.score, g2.adnumber) >= (g1.score, g1.adnumber) 
AND g1.subject_id = g2.subject_id
where g1.adnumber = 'demonumber'
GROUP BY g1.adnumber , g1.subject_id , g1.score 
ORDER BY g1.subject_id , rank;
```